# Strawberry & Raspberry jam discoloration

Tags: jam

For about 3 yrs i have been using a jam/jelly maker. After a few months of storage, the strawberry&raspberry discolor. I do follow the canning bath directions. The only thing I do not follow is I decrease sugar to 1/2 or 1 cup (vs directions of 2cups). I have tried bottled lemon juice as directions say. Still discolors after 3-4 months. I have my water tested and it always passes the test. I water bath the jars after filling for 10 min as recommended. I’m at a loss and wonder if I’m overlooking something? I appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: What color does it discolor to?

Comment: How much fruit to that much sugar?

Comment: Have the lids sealed ? Become concave and strongly held to the jar . If air leaks it will tend to get brown color.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. As for color, its a paler red not vibrant. I use 3 1/2 C fresh strawberries/1/2 cup sugar. After they cool from boil bath, I unscrew lids make sure the seal is good. Store down cool basement

Comment: I'm worried about the 'unscrew lids to make sure the seal is good'… surely that will break the seal.

Comment: @Tetsujin I assume Marcia meant “unscrew the rings”.

Comment: Be careful when modifying canning recipes. The sugar isn't there just for the taste, it's also a preservative in a high enough proportion. By so drastically reducing the sugar in your recipe, you may be making it less safe, regardless of canning method.

Comment: Thank you senschen! You are right, I will modify and test that out. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

For strawberry jam, the discoloration that happens over time is when the [pelargonidin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelargonidin), i.e. the red color breaks down, leaving you with a brownish-red or greyish mush instead of a vibrant red jam.

The breaking down is sped up by a warm environment and exposure to light, starting with long cooking time (probably not an issue in your case), and continuing in storage. The easiest way is to store the jars in the freezer - they will be protected from light and once thawed, still have the enticing red of freshly cooked strawberry jam. We pulled out a jar the other day that was from last year and there was no visual difference noticeable.

Alternatives are adding a small amount of a more stable red color, e.g. black currant, aronia, elderberry or even beet juice. It may change the “pure” strawberry flavor, though.

The more color is in your jam at the beginning, the longer will it stay red. If you have the choice, choose fully ripe fruit and cultivars that are red all through the fruit instead of ones with a paler interior. But in the end, freezing is the safest method.

As raspberries’ red is based on the same chemical components, I would assume the same mechanisms apply as for strawberries. But raspberry jam never lasts long enough in our home to change color, so I don’t have experimental data available.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephie. I will consider freezing. I’ve never put glass in the freezer before, but worth a try!! I do the boil bath, let them cool, unscrew lids to make sure the seal is good, then store down my cool basement. And the jam thaws good? Hmmm.

Comment: Thaws to just as it was before. My mom has some years filled a whole freezer drawer with strawberry jam jars. We use the twist-off type of jars, so maybe do an experiment first to make sure that the seal in the mason jar type stays intact.

Comment: Thank you again Stephie....I’m on an experimental mission. I appreciate all your advice. I hope to be ready for strawberry season!!